# conv.askToDeepLink is not a function

Tags: actions-on-google

The old way of invoke the askToDeepLink are no more working in DialogFlow even in V1.

```
 app.askToDeepLink('Great! Looks like we can do that in the Android app.', 'tool for Android',
     'sample://scheduleMeeting', 'com.sample', 'handle this for you');
```

Anybody know the way to invoke askToDeepLink in V2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to connect one of your Android apps with your Assistant app, you should try this.

```
app.intent('ask_to_deep_link_detail', (conv) => {
  const options = {
    destination: 'Google',
    url: 'example://gizmos',
    package: 'com.example.gizmos',
    reason: 'handle this for you',
  };
  conv.ask('Great! looks like maybe we can do that in the app.');
  conv.ask(new DeepLink(options));
});
```

**Getting the results of the helper**

If the user accepts the link, the dialog with your app will end and you will not receive further requests. If they reject the link, you will receive another request with the intent `actions.intent.LINK` and a status argument:

```
app.intent('ask_to_deep_link_confirmation', (conv, params, response) => {
  conv.ask('Okay maybe we can take care of that another time.');
});
```

I hope this helps.